# could not deduce template argument for T* from FieldType* (Visual C++ only)

Tags: templates, visual-c++, c++14, decltype, template-argument-deduction

This code compiles OK on **g++ ([Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4e35d658effca3df))**, but not **Visual C++ ([rextester](http://rextester.com/MOH83998))** - both online and my desktop.

*It is a simplified version of a much larger Visual Studio 2015 project.*

```
class AAA{
    public: template<class T> static T*  test(T* hqi){
        return hqi;
    }
};
class TTT3{ 
    public: int d;   //In real case, it is some class, but same error nonetheless.
    decltype(AAA::test(&d)) dfd=AAA::test(&d);  //<-- error only Visual C++
};
int main(){
    int b;
    decltype(AAA::test(&b)) dfd=AAA::test(&b);  //OK for boths
}
```

> 'T *AAA::test(T *)': could not deduce template argument for 'T *' from
>   'int TTT3::* '

**Question**

- Why?  Is my code wrong? - I don't think so.
- How to make it compile in Visual C++?  I need it.

Comment: How about `decltype(AAA::test(std::declval<int*>()))`?

Comment: @Oktalist Thank, I can use it as a workaround. Now I know that the problematic part is in "decltype".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Visual Studio specific bug. According to the standard:

[[expr.unary.op/4]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.unary#op-4)

> A pointer to member is only formed when an explicit & is used and its
>   operand is a qualified-id not enclosed in parentheses. [ Note: That
>   is, the expression &(qualified-id), where the qualified-id is enclosed
>   in parentheses, does not form an expression of type “pointer to
>   member”. Neither does qualified-id, because there is no implicit
>   conversion from a qualified-id for a non-static member function to the
>   type “pointer to member function” as there is from an lvalue of
>   function type to the type “pointer to function” ([conv.func]). **Nor is
>   &unqualified-id a pointer to member, even within the scope of the
>   unqualified-id's class.** — end note ]

The text in bold is what VC++ doesn't do properly inside decltype for whatever reason. Since hoping that Microsoft will fix it is a fools hope, another workaround you can do is to add the following overload:

```
template<class C, typename T>
static T* test(T C::*);
```

<kbd>[Live Example](http://rextester.com/VBVXU95281)</kbd>

Possibly in a `#ifdef/#endif` block that checks for VC++. Not defining it prevents it being picked silently outside of an unevaluated context such as a decltype, albeit with only a link time error.

Comment: I am interested in your thought process that you used to come up with this great solution.  .... By the way, this is not the first time you help me, thank a lot.

Comment: @javaLover - Well. Step 1 was to check the semantics of & according to the standard to see which compiler errs. Then I set out to force `decltype` to deduce the correct type without you having to change the definition of `dfd`. If VC++ wants to pass a pointer to member, I figured we'd accept it and return a regular pointer. At first I returned `nullptr`, but then figured deleting it would prevent subtle bugs. Then it was just a matter of checking if using deleted functions as unevaluated operands is okay, and it is. Thus the answer was sculpted. Hope this ramble is of help to you :)

Comment: @javaLover - I amended the answer a bit. Please see the fixed part about deleting it. You shouldn't do that. It's ill-formed, I was wrong.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't look valid to me because the first `&d` in

```
decltype(AAA::test(&d)) dfd=AAA::test(&d);
```

is an implicit use of `this` outside of the member initializer.  I can't find any exception in the Standard making an implicit use of `this` inside `decltype` valid, plus all three major compilers complain if you replace the `&d` with explicit `&this->d`.

Unfortunately, I don't see any easy way around this, unless you substitute the actual type of `d` or make a typedef for it.

Comment: Thank.   I doubt .... It would work if I change to `int* dfd=AAA::test(&d);`.  Therefore, the problem is probably in `decltype` only.   It should not compilable if your hypothesis is correct. (?)